# Relationship that have all the multiple types in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get the nodes from a that are of both TYPE1 and TYPE2, but in the documentation it only lists how to do it for TYPE1 or TYPE2

```
(a)-[r:TYPE1|TYPE2]->(b)
```

Is there an operator that functions as **"and"**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you are looking for is the `ALL` predicate on the relationship types.

Basically it means also that nodes `b` will have at least `x` relationships from `a` where `x` is the amount of different relationship types you pass as parameter.

Here the list of relationship types parameter is simulated with a `WITH` :

```
WITH ['typeA','typeB'] as validTypes
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH b, collect(distinct(r)) as types, validTypes
WHERE ALL(x in validTypes WHERE x IN types)
RETURN b
```

If you would execute the same by passing the validTypes as query param, it will look like this :

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH b, collect(distinct(r)) as types
WHERE ALL(x in {validTypes} WHERE x IN types)
RETURN b
```

Here is an example console : http://console.neo4j.org/r/3zdml9

Answer (score 1):

A relationship can have only a single type. So in the example you gave:

```
(a)-[r:TYPE1|TYPE2]->(b)
```

the variable `r` is bound to a relationship of either `TYPE1` or `TYPE2`. It does not make sense to match on a relationship of `TYPE1` and `TYPE2` because such a relationship will not exist.

If you are trying to match on a **Node** that has multiple *labels* you can do it like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)
MATCH (a:Agent)
RETURN a
```

`a` will only be nodes that have both `Person` and `Agent` labels.

Comment: I have nodes that have multiple relations. I want to get nodes that match relation types I have in an array. Realized I worded my question poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Cypher does not have `and` to check node a and b has `TYPE1` and `TYPE 2`.
But you can try to write `TYPE2` in where like this:

```
match (a)-[r:TYPE1]-(b)
where ((a)-[:TYPE2]-(b))
return a,b
```

Also you can use `with` like this:

```
match (a)-[r:TYPE1]-(b)
with a,b
match (a)-[r2:TYPE2]-(b)
return a,b
```

Wish these codes will help you.